# Hide Prices everywhere but allow ordering

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules

We have a client who is using a legacy developed webstore, but we are looking to move them to magento 2. They currently have a web store with no pricing features, as each client has a different contracted price. I am curious about to do this with Magento? The goal would be to have no pricing, no cart totals, no pricing in order / email summary. The store will operate only once logged and registration will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this, and it basically requires modifications to the themes files.

You basically have two options:

1) Full purge of pricing via theme pages
2) CSS only changes to hide pricing blocks (still there if they want to inspect), but may require a few additional edits such as to the email templates

As a developer you can turn on Template Path Hints and look for the blocks and template files that display pricing data. If you are going to the trouble of modifying the theme files, then I would also add a System Config option to allow you to toggle on and off the pricing.

Areas that need adjustment are:

1. Category and product pages
2. Wishlist
3. Checkout
4. Email templates for order confirmation
5. Order History
6. RSS feeds
7. Any 3rd party extensions??

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at extensions?

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-hide-price.html/

I've not done this myself but in theory you could configure to hide for all customer groups

Although if you want to code something yourself you will have to use plugins. Depending on how much customisation is in your theme you may still have to do some template work though.